# Hearing the time signature switch of a cover of the "Mission Impossible Theme"

Tags: guitar, rhythm, time-signatures, meter

The original 1966 score of "Mission impossible" was written entirely in 5/4 time (you can listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGSUjuSBt1A)).

For the first movie staring Tom Cruise, the theme was rewritten by two U2 band members, and after the initial theme (still in 5/4) it changes it time signature to 4/4, you can listen to it [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aJbzv1ppcVU).

Now I am listening this [cover version](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IXa2pNGVj8) of Paolo Sereno as played by Sungha Jung. And here the intro is also in 5/4, but when the melody starts (around 16s, see [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5IXa2pNGVj8&t=0m15s)) he also seems to switch the time signature, but it does not seem to be 4/4, I guess its 6/4 but I am not sure? So can you hear what time signature he plays when the melody starts in?

Comment: My ears are hearing a bit of a stumble in the tempo.  Is it possible it's just a goof-up in the playing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it continues in 5/4. With a couple of little glitches, but supposed to be still in 5/4. There's no distinct rhythm change, just tiny fluffs. Still incredible for one of tender years, though !

Comment: Exactly right; the performer loses the tempo when the melodic line enters, but it's still 5/4.

Comment: For me, it's easier to count it as 10/8 so that the strong beats are on 1 if you count 123 123 12 12 ...

Answer (score 1):

I agree that this is more 10/8 than 5/4:
ONE two three ONE two three one-two one-two
ONE two three ONE two three one-two one-two

and I would say the same of Dave Brubeck's "Take Five." To me a true 5/4 would be
one two ONE two three
one two ONE two three

or

one two three ONE two
one two three ONE two

both of which feel very jaggedy compared to 10/8.

Comment: Isn’t that a normal case of syncopation. By your rule a lot of 4/4 pop music would need to be Written as 8/8.

Comment: Doesn't "Take Five" go ONE-and TWO-and THREE-and FOUR-and FIVE-and throughout? Even the opening vamp keeps the TWO-and THREE-and instead of going ONE-and two-AND three-and.